# How can I use a custom application.properties file in a native quarkus image in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, native, quarkus, application.properties

I have my native quarkus image in docker.
I want to change the application.properties only for one environment, in a docker-compose. I don't want to use environment variables.
How can I use a custom application.properties? I haven't seen anything in quarkus guides, stackoverflow, or other platform.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the file when you are building the container image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#quarkus-config-config_quarkus.config.locations, to define additional configuration files, external to the jar, image or container.

Remember that configurations that are build time, are not going to be reread and adjusted even if you override them this way.